# How to correctly set default text with GTK 3

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3

I've tried everything but I'm so lost. Here is what I need to achieve:

```
    backupDirs = gtk_entry_new();
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), backupDirs, 1, 1, 1, 1);
    gtk_entry_set_placeholder_text(*backupDirs,"Placeholder text here");
```

I don't understand how to correctly pass the string into the function.

Comment: try changing *backupDirs -> backupDirs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a pointer to a `GtkEntry` as the first argument of `gtk_entry_set_placeholder_text`. You didn't show your declaration of `backupDirs`, but since `gtk_entry_new` returns a `GtkWidget *`, I assume it's something like

```
GtkWidget *backupDirs = gtk_entry_new()
```

So you need to cast it to `GtkEntry *`, using the built-in macros:

```
gtk_entry_set_placeholder_text(GTK_ENTRY(backupDirs), "Placeholder text here");
```